# Sagemaker lifecycle config: could not find conda environment conda_python3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

the below script should run a notebook called prepTimePreProcessing whenever a AWS notebook instance starts runing.
however I am getting "could not find conda environment conda_python3" error from the lifecycle config file.

```bash
set -e
ENVIRONMENT=python3
NOTEBOOK_FILE="/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/prepTimePreProcessing.ipynb"
echo "Activating conda env"
source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate "$ENVIRONMENT"
echo "Starting notebook"
nohup jupyter nbconvert  --to notebook --inplace --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=600 --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python3 --execute "$NOTEBOOK_FILE" &
```

Any help whould be appreciated.

Comment: I can execute a notebook with your script without any issues. Are you using Notebook Instances or Studio? If it's Notebook instances, can you run this shell script from your terminal and let me know if it executes successfully?

Comment: when executing /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate python3, the following error shows up: bash: /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Assuming no environment problems, if you open a terminal in the instance in use and run:

```bash
conda env list
```

the result should also contain this line:

```
python3 /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3
```

After that, you can create a .sh script inside /home/ec2-user/SageMaker containing all the code to run. This way it also becomes versionable by being a persisted file in the instance space and not inside an external configuration.

The on-start.sh/on-create.sh (from this point I will simply call it script.sh) file becomes trivially:

```bash
# PARAMETERS
ENVIRONMENT=python3

# conda env
source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate "$ENVIRONMENT";
echo "'$ENVIRONMENT' env activated"
```

In the lifecycle config, on the other hand, just write a few lines to invoke the previously created script.sh:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

SETUP_FILE=/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/script.sh

echo "Run setup script"
sh "$SETUP_FILE"
echo "Setup completed!"
```

### Extra

If you want to add a safety check so that the .sh file is read correctly regardless of line breaks, I would also add a conversion:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

set -e

SETUP_FILE=/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/script.sh

# convert script to unix format
echo "Converting setup script into unix format"
sudo yum -y install dos2unix > /dev/null 2>&1
dos2unix "$SETUP_FILE" > /dev/null 2>&1

echo "Run setup script"
sh "$SETUP_FILE"
echo "Setup completed!"
```